# How to mock CLLocationManager in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mocking

I was not able to override the location property of CLLocationManager.
Any ideas on how to do that?

If I do:

```
class MockCLLocationManager: CLLocationManager {
    var location {
        get {
            return CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error: `'@objc' getter for non-'@objc' property`

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

This might be a bit late answer but since I was also looking for the same thing here it is:

You would you use a opposite approach. First declare a protocol you will use in case of actual CLLocationManager

```
protocol LocationManager{
    var location:CLLocation? {get}
}
```

And make the CLLocationManager conform to it

```
extension CLLocationManager:LocationManager{}
```

This way you can mock the location manager in your tests like this:

```
class MockLocationManager:LocationManager{
         var location:CLLocation? = CLLocation(latitude: 55.213448, longitude: 20.608194)
}
```

But can also pass CLLocationManager instead of it in production code.

See more here: https://blog.eliperkins.me/mocks-in-swift-via-protocols/

**Edit fixed broken link**

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I have fix the link with https://blog.eliperkins.me/mocks-in-swift-via-protocols/

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
fileprivate class MockLocationManager : CLLocationManager {
    var mockLocation: CLLocation?
    override var location: CLLocation? {
        return mockLocation
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and on the test itself, just assign a clllocation to the mockLocation

```
let locationManager = MockLocationManager()
locationManager.mockLocation = anyLocation
```

and test your inner logic like:

```
yourClass.locationManager(locationManager, didUpdateLocations: [anyLocation])
```